Configure Threat detection features on CISCO ASA for VPN connections
for VPN remote connections via CISCO Anyconnect clients I need to configue 2 Threat detection features on my CISCO ASA firewall to protect our VPN:
1. Credential login attempts
This could be brute force  (Username & password guessing)
Here I need to configue 2 values:
a) hold-down <minutes>
defines the period after the last failed attempt during which consecutive failures are counted.
b) threshold <count>
is the number of failed authentication attempts required within the hold-down period to trigger a shun.

2. incomplete connection attempts
This could DoS/initiation attacks or network problems
Here I need to configue the same 2 values:
a) hold-down <minutes>
defines the period after the last initiation attempt during which consecutive connection attempts are counted.
b) threshold <count>
is the number of connection attempts required within the hold-down period to trigger a shun.

We only have 20 users of which max. 3-4 are connected via VPN at the same time.
However, the data accessed by users is very sensitive
Does anyone have experience with practical values or which values would you recommend for hold-down and threshold?
